# How do I make multiple widgets with transition between them on single page

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a sliding bottom sheet that shows one widget. I want that widget to be replaced by another on button press. Then, that widget will also be replaceable by another and so on. These replacements need to happen with slide transition.

I've seen multiple topics on SO regarding sliding widgets from and to sides of the screen, but all these solutions seem to be very direct and built around raw transitions and widget replacement.

Is there some plugin for these kind of layouts or maybe I can put `Navigator` to some kind of use here?

The final result i seek is something very close to gif below:

[image: Slide demonstration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest a `Navigator` inside another `Navigator` take a look at the `Navigator` docs. You could use one `Navigator` to the app in general and another `Navigator` to the bottom sheet.

If you don't want to deal with a `Navigator` for some reason, then take a look at the [`Animated` Widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/animation), like `SlideTransition`.